# Why is my class name not changing and moving span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created what I thought was a really simple code with JS and HTML.  When the user starts to type into the textbox, I want `.clearBtn` to change it's className, and slide to the left.  Why is that not happening?

### http://jsfiddle.net/qgy8Ly5L/

My JS:

```
function checkInput(text) {

    if (text != null || text != "") {
    $("#clearBtn1").addClass("show");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
.clearBtn show {
    left: -15px;
}
```

to

```
.show {
    left: -15px;
}
```

in the css

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgy8Ly5L/10/)

Comment: Thank you.  That fix was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is now `CSS` class by `show`. It should be

```
.show {
    left: -15px;
}
```

Instead of

```
.clearBtn show {
    left: -15px;
}
```

```js
function checkInput(text) {
    if (text) {
        $("#clearBtn1").addClass("show");
    }
}
```

```css
.clearBtn {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
.show {
    left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkInput(this.value)" />
<span id="clearBtn1" class="clearBtn">X</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the current code from what I understand.

1.you first need to remove the class '.clearbutton'

2.the comparisons operators should be used like the below code

So you may try this:

```
function checkInput(text) {
if (text !== null || text !== "") {
$("#clearBtn1").removeClass("clearBtn");
$("#clearBtn1").addClass("show");
  }
}
```

and the css class `show` be like:

```
. show {
left: -15px;
 }
```

[**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qgy8Ly5L/9/)